# AWS Fargate private subnet, pulling from ECR

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've Fargate task defined in the private subnet (no internet access). I defined endpoints (PrivateLinks) for the: s3 (gateway), ecr.api, ecr.dkr, ecr.logs (interfaces). I added egress on 443/TCP to the s3 gateway and ecr. I set `enable_dns_hostnames = true` `enable_dns_support   = true` in the vpc.
I'm getting weird error which I do not know how to troubleshoot: `CannotPullContainerError: ref pull has been retried 5 time(s): failed to copy: httpReaderSeeker: failed open: failed to do request: Get https://prod-eu-west-2-starport-layer-bucket.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/`

Any ideas? I spent today 7 hours going through docs, no success... I'm using Fargate 1.40.

Comment: You shouldn't be defining egress rules on VPC endpoints, you should be defining ingress rules. I suggest going through this official tutorial step-by-step https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/setting-up-aws-privatelink-for-amazon-ecs-and-amazon-ecr/

Comment: @arabv did you solve it? I have the same error using NACLS.

Comment: Yep. I don't remember exactly but I needed to add proper endpoints as per https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/vpc-endpoints.html

Comment: For me it was a security group. I had made a change to the (ECS) services' security group, mostly to keep tfsec happy(-er) as such it could not pull the image and failed to start with the error mentioned by the op

Answer (score 2):

When you see that we are trying to get the pre-signed URL from S3: `https://prod-eu-west-2-starport-layer-bucket...`. It means that we had passed the permission problem and is encountering `networking issue` when trying to get the ECR image artifact from AWS managed S3.

It is probably caused by one or some of the following issues:

- VPC-Endpoints (PrivateLink) setting
- Security Groups inbound rules
- VPC subnet Network-ACL restriction

Follow this document and check line by line might help to debug the problem: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/vpc-endpoints.html

Comment: In my case the cause of the trouble was missing assignment of route tables to the S3 gateway endpoint

Answer (score 1):

the "CannotPullContainerError" seems to indicate that ECS is not able to get the container from ECR or dockerhub or wherever you're trying to pull the container from.

If your ECS TaskDefinition is pointing to a container in ECR, then ECS will try to pull it from there. And it can only pull it from ECR if the TaskDefinition has a TaskExecutionRole which have privileges of pulling your container from ECR.

Can you confirm that your ECS TaskDefinition has an ECS TaskExecutionRole which has proper ecr privs?